# Potential energy of an Atwood Machine

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, potential-energy, spring

> The two weights on the left have equal masses $m$ and are connected by a massless spring of force constant $k$. The weight on the right has mass $M=2m$, and the pulley is massless and frictionless. The coordinate $x$ is the extension of the spring from its equilibrium length; that is, the length of the spring is $l_e+x$ where $l_e$ is the equilibrium length (with all the weights in position and $M$ held stationary).
>
> (a) Show that the total potential energy (spring + gravitational) is just $U=\frac{1}{2}kx^2$ (plus a constant that we can take to be zero).
>
> [image: Atwood Machine]

**My Attempt**

I allow the length of the string to be fixed as $L$, and so I have written the two potential energies (grav and elastic) separately as:
$$\begin{align}
 U_\text{grav} &= mgy + mg(y+l_e+x) + 2m(L-y)g \nonumber\\
 &= mgl_e+2mLg+mgx \\
 U_\text{spring} &= \frac{1}{2}kx^2
\end{align} 
$$

But combining the two equations and ignoring the constant terms, I still have an $x$ term in my expression for $U$. I would appreciate it if someone could point out my mistake here, which I'm pretty sure is an elementary one. Thank you!.

**EDIT**

Perhaps just a bonus question, I have expressed the kinetic energy of the system to be 
$$ T = \frac12m\dot{y}^2 + \frac12(2m)\dot{y}^2 + \frac12{m}(\dot{y}+\dot{x})^2$$
where my concern is with the last term. Considering how my first answer for the potential energy is wrong, I'm guessing the velocity of the lower mass is not as simple as $\dot{y}+\dot{x}$?

p.s. This is from Taylor's Classical Mechanics, Problem 13.23

Comment: People are voting that this does not fit our homework policy; I think "how do I get rid of this $x$ term in my expression for $U$" is a sufficiently specific physics concept but you should be aware that it is a little vague.

Comment: Troy, take care on the previous comment, on it depends the reopening of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in your diagram we have a bunch of different lengths that don't quite add up; I'm going to therefore assume that all of the boxes drawn have negligible height and the rope connecting the one box of mass $m$ with the box of mass $2m$ has length $L + \pi R$ where $R$ is the radius of the pulley, so that we don't have to include that amount of rope in $L$.

Now the formula for gravitational potential energy of a particle is $U = m~ g~ h.$ Let's therefore put the pulley at a height $H$ above some ground. The remaining sum for the gravitational potential energies is simply:
$$ m~g~(H - y) + m~g~(H - y - l_e - x) + 2m~g~(H - L + y),$$and indeed a lot of these terms cancel to give $$4m~g~H - m~g~l_e - m~g~x.$$
So **yes**, this $x$ is a real thing, you have not screwed it up in this form. However: we have to be very clear what we mean by "equilibrium" and hence $l_e$.

See, you're treating equilibrium as the equilibrium *without load*, i.e. $l_e$ is measured when $m = 0$. That's why you're saying that the potential energy is just $\frac 12 k x^2.$ Now let's see what this does to our total potential energy,
$$U = \frac 12 k x^2 - m g x + C_1$$ for some constant $C_1$. Complete the square:$$U = \frac 12 k \left (x - \frac{mg}{k}\right)^2 + C_2.$$
Now recall the principle of friction/drag: friction and drag always oppose the velocity and therefore have negative power; they theoretically sap energy from a system until it ends up at a minimum of potential energy and zero kinetic energy, which is a sort of "equilibrium under load." And we see from the above that $x$ is not $0$ at this equilibrium under load; it is at $x = \frac{mg}{k}.$

If we define the true length for equilibrium-under-load $l_E = l_e + \frac{mg}{k}$ and renormalize $x$ to use that above, then we still have $-m~g~x$ from the gravitational potential energy but now $\frac12 k (x + l_E - l_e)^2$ for the spring potential energy, and the cross term from the latter is precisely the $m~g~x$ that cancels the former term.

This is a nice feature that you should appreciate for ideal springs in general; when they are subjected to a constant force they basically just change their equilibrium lengths but not their spring constants nor their effective energy about that equilibrium. You can mostly "wave away" the details. It just happens to be that you waved away half of the details and forgot to similarly wave away the other half!

**Edit:** as for that bonus question, you're wrong; it is just that simple. Put it at some displacement $z = x + y + l_e,$ what is $\dot z$?

Comment: If you put it this way, now I see why $\dot{z}=\dot{x}+\dot{y}$. I appreciate the explanation, and have noted the comment above. I shall attempt to be more specific in the future. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Hint 1: Think about how the system will act when moving *freely*, in other words, don't think about a situation where someone holds on to $M$ and then pulls the second one of the masses $m$ down.

Hint 2: Think about the two masses $m$ connected by the spring as one system. How does the center of mass of this combined system move when the spring is not in its equilibrium position? How is it related to the motion of the entire system?